Novogene sequencing archives
We have recently received the sequencing files from this company. For each sample, two files with extension Bam and bam.pbi are available. I would like to ask what is the meaning of the numbers behind the sequence and the quality for a specific sequence.


Please don't post images of text, and especially not gigantic images where the text is just a tiny part of it. Open the file on a computer not a phone and paste an example of its contents. I can't understand what it is from that image and you also haven't told us which of the two file types you are showing us. Please [edit] your question and clarify.

I have never heard of "PFI" files. BAM files are a format that contains the reads either with out without mapping information. What exactly you have, and how it was generated and processed you must ask the company. Only they know. Call or email them. You pay for it, so make use of that.

Most likely a pbi file? bam index?
